# Azure Devops Pipeline build explorer

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm beginning playing around with the Azure Pipeline and have a hard time figuring out what is the output of my builds and where they are stored.

Is there a way to explore files contained in builds?  I feel like I'm blind when using those built-in variables without knowing whats behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts) is a list of predefined variables for referencing files in build pipeline tasks.

If you want to get more visibility to the files I suggest you create and configure your own build agent, instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts).

Comment: I finally understood that I wasn't producing an actual artifact after running my ng build --prod statement.  It was just compiling it.  Once I exported that into an artifact I can download the actual build result!   Took me a while to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to "explore" a build is to publish to a "drop" location using:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

After this open up the Artifacts dropdown in the top-right and explore your build